# How to run two different computers on the same hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

I am throwing around the idea of having two computers - a desktop at home, and portable pc for my digital mixer.

What I want to accomplish is having a single hard drive that would plug into a dock that I could remove from one computer and place in the other, so that my experience would be nearly seamless between the two computers. It would need to be running Windows 10.

If this wouldn’t work, I know I have simpler, less cool options.

Comment: install the same apps on both computers and share a data drive

Comment: You can even have some **applications** on a shared drive, with the *caveats* that some programs *require* they be run from C:/, and that app settings changed by one user *might* affect another user. 7-Zip and IrfanView run well on other drives, MS Office  might, or might not.

Comment: Remoting into the portable PC from the desktop seems like the 'sensible' option

Answer (score 0):

The computers would need to be nearly identical for common drivers to work on both machines.

Also a common user id would not likely work (different registries in each computer).

The idea is not all that practical.

What you likely need (what I have always needed) is the data I am working with.

This you can put on a USB Drive and use a sync program (I use Sync Back Pro, but there are numerous such Apps) to keep the data on the USB drive in sync on both computers.

This is a sturdier approach overall.

Answer (score 0):

Both the desktop and portable(laptop)  will have their own boot disks, you cant share that.  But you can share a data disk.  I use a USB disk routinely for this purpose.

Comment: So like, I could still use a 5.25 hot swap hard drive bay to insert a shared data disk, specifically for the files I want the two computers to share? Once again, one of the PCs would be my home desktop, the other would be a portable rackmount PC that would be in a rack with some other recording equipment.